# Issue with GlobalExceptionHandler Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a fatal error which I do not know how to solve,even after several days of trying.
The error that i have is :
"Could not load file or assembly 'GlobalExceptionHandler, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ed6585c9914bae60' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

For more details:

-I had never before seen this error but when I deployed a project I encountered the error cited above...

-So ,after this change, I assume that the action mentioned before caused me this error.

-For this, I executed orders at "Windows PowerShell" as: stsadm-o-name deletesolution solutionName.wsp to remove the solution completely.

-After that, I made sure that the project I deployed ​​is no longer in my server.

-Later, when I logged to the" Sharepoint Central Administration" on port 24427. ,in hoping not to see the error anymore ,i saw that the error has not disappeared .

So , now i no longer have access to the " Sharepoint Central Administration",as the error remains.

I will be grateful to any proposal from you.

Thank you & sorry for my english. .

Answer (score 0):

Please try out below few steps:-

1.Deploy the assembly to GAC or copy the dll to the bin folder of your web application
2.Add the assembly info in your web.config assemblies section and in the safe controls section.
3.Redeploy the solution.

This should help.